# How to get site homepage from plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, jquery, ajax

I am creating a plugin that has a preview, kind of like the theme customizer preview. It displays the users site in an Iframe. The issue is that I can't seem to be able to get the users homepage using the standard way of grabbing them, such as:

```
<iframe id="preview_frame" src="<?php get_bloginfo('url'); ?>"></iframe>
```

Or:

```
<iframe id="preview_frame" src="<?php get_home_url(); ?>"></iframe>
```

Can anyone shed some light on the proper way of doing this? Is their a specific way to display the site as a preview? I am using a hook to [disable the admin bar in the preview](http://yoast.com/disable-wp-admin-bar/), so if there is an elegant way to create a preview without the admin bar, it would be very good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just not using the right function. Try using this:

`<iframe id="preview_frame" src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></iframe>`

Comment: Thanks Jared. You were right, I was using the wrong function. I am guessing the functions I was using only work for themes, and not plugins. I am now using home_url and it works great.